# Parallel.For maintain input list order on output list

Tags: c#, list, parallel-processing, webforms

I'd like some input on keeping the order of a list during heavy-duty operations that I decided to try to do in a parallel manner to see if it boosts performance. (It did!)

I came up with a solution, but since this was my first attempt at anything parallel, I'd need someone to slap my hands if I did something very stupid.

There's a query that returns a list of card owners, sorted by name, then by date of birth. This needs to be rendered in a table on a web page (ASP.Net WebForms). The original coder decided he would construct the table cell-by-cell (`TableCell`), add them to rows (`TableRow`), then each row to the table. So no GridView, allegedly its performance is bad, but the performance was very poor regardless :).

The database query returns in no time, the most time is spent on looping through the results and adding table cells etc.

I made the following method to maintain the original order of the list:

```cs
private TableRow[] ComposeRows(List<CardHolder> queryResult)   
{
    int queryElementsCount = queryResult.Count();
    // array with the query's size
    var rowArray = new TableRow[queryElementsCount];

    Parallel.For(0, queryElementsCount, i =>
    {
        var row = new TableRow();
        var cell = new TableCell();

        // various operations, including simple ones such as:
        cell.Text = queryResult[i].Name;
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        // here I'm adding the current item to it's original index 
        // to maintain order in the output list
        rowArray[i] = row;
    });
    return rowArray;
}
```

So as you can see, because I'm returning a very different type of data (`List<CardHolder> -> TableRow[]`), I can't just simply omit the ordering from the original query to do it after the operations.

<strike>Also, I also thought it would be a good idea to `Dispose()` the objects at the end of each loop, because the query can return a huge list and letting cell and row objects pile up in the heap could impact performance.(?)</strike>

How badly did I do? Does anyone have a better solution in case mine is flawed?

After testing, with a |2000| array, `StopWatch` says parallel composition is done in 63 ms (165082 ticks), and serial composition is done in 267 ms (698222). Both including adding rows to- (`table.Rows.AddRange()`), then rendering the `Table`. Without adding and rendering, times are 33ms/87541t for parallel and 178ms/467068t for serial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little code-review:

- the 2 calls to `Dispose()` should be removed. At best they are harmless.
- take a critical look at how you obtain `originalIndex`. It should always turn out to be equal to `i` so you don't need it.

But aside from this bit of streamlining there is not much to improve. It is doubtful that doing this in parallel will help much, or that this is the real bottleneck in your code. I suspect most time will be spent processing the results in `TableRow[]` .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback kind sir! You are right about the indexing. I was pondering a lot on the implementation so my brain got a little overloaded and failed to rationally review it by the end.